# what is the correct syntax for query

Tags: php, mysql

how can I get this syntax work? I got it to work with one of the result. But I want to 
 get out query from 3. (`result1`, `result2`, `result3`).

```
$sql  = "SELECT modulid=1 FROM oppgave WHERE resultat resultat2 resultat3 is NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

any tip how to query 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

If you want to check that any one should be null of of resultat, resultat2 and resultat3, then use below query:

```
SELECT moduleid 
FROM oppgave 
WHERE modulid=1 and (resultat is null or resultat2 is null or resultat3 is NULL) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to check that all resultat, resultat2 and resultat3 should be null, then use below query:

```
SELECT moduleid 
FROM oppgave 
WHERE modulid=1 and (resultat is null and resultat2 is null and resultat3 is NULL) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query like this..

```
SELECT *
FROM oppgave
WHERE modulid=1
AND
coalesce(resultat, resultat2, resultat3) IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

---

Proceed like this..

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling); 
echo "<br>"; 
while ($nextrow= mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "Besvarelse: <br>" . $nextrow['besvarelse']; "<br>Modulid: " . $nextrow['modulid'];
}
```

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: thank you for answer! i think this is the thing i need. but i get nothing output from my query.

Comment: i use this for fetching the restult. mabt i done somethink wrong there: $result = mysql_query($sql, $tilkobling); 
echo "<br>";
while ($nextrow= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "Besvarelse: <br>" . $nextrow['besvarelse'];
"<br>Modulid: " . $nextrow['modulid'];

Comment: Try the new query .. I edited the answer. But you didnt answer my question whether the above query worked on your MySQL console or phpMyAdmin.

Comment: ill try convert the connection to mysqli now

Comment: still not get to output from the 3 rows. only from 1

Comment: now i got it wo rok! thanks, you are a life saver! no i got to find uot how to send back result to the table. i have these rows. corrected by1,correctedby2,correctedby3 and give back result approved or not to resulat1,resultat2 and resultat3

Comment: this is working if the result1 is NULL. if result2 is NULL i im overwriting the result1